# How is Statement 2 not a correct explanation for Statement 1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

This is excerpted from the May 7, 2012 JEE Main exam paper and mark scheme:

> > Let $f(x) = \sin (x)$, $g(x) = x$
> > Statement 1: $f(x) \leqslant g(x)$ for $x$ in $(0,\infty)$
> > Statement 2: $f(x) \leqslant 1$ for $x$ in $(0,\infty)$ but $g(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$
>
> Statement 1 is true, Statement 2 is true, and Statement 2 is not a correct explanation for Statement 1.

Now, since the range of $\sin (x)$ is $[-1,1]$ the first part of Statement 2 is True; clearly, the second part of Statement 2 is also true; so, isn't Statement 2 in fact a correct explanation for Statement 1, which is also true?

Comment: @iateawalrus: the OP is about an answer to a JEE Main question. Why not include that question? It seems to be "Are Statement 1 and Statement 2 true? Is Statement 2 a proof of Statement 1?" but it could be something else. From experience, there are often crucial details omitted in an incomplete question.

Comment: @Taladris I have asked the question in the last two lines and have not omitted any information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no, because $f(x)\not\to\infty$ and $g(x)\to \infty$ does not necessarily imply that $f(x)\leq g(x)$ **for all $x$** in the interval$.$

For example, $\sin(x)>e^x-2$ for $x$ close to $0$, but $\sin(x)\not\to\infty$ and $e^x-2\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

You misinterpreted the question as asking whether $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$ is a true statement for the given functions $f$ and $g.$ But the question is actually asking whether it is true that **for all functions $f$ and $g,$** $(1)\Rightarrow(2).$ iateawalrus's counterexample (the accepted answer) $$f(x)=\sin(x)\\g(x)=e^x-2$$ shows that this is false.

(The cited exam paper merely happens to display an $f,g$ pair for which $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$ is true. The point being made is that two statements being true does not necessarily mean that one is a correct explanation of the other.)

Putting it another way: you had failed to recognise that the implication given to you is implicitly universally quantified, reading it instead as a propositional-logic implication and reading $f$ and $g$ as fixed functions instead of as variable functions.

Comment: Thank you so much! This further clarified my doubt!